# Error by sending phone number from PFCloud to parse.com with twilio

Tags: ios, objective-c, node.js, parse-platform, twilio

I trying to send a phone number from an ios app to Parse.com server, through Twilio, to sent a verification code in SMS, I did exactly as the parse guide, etc., but still I keep getting the error:
"[Error]: Uh oh, something went wrong (Code: 141, Version: 1.12.0)",
The code in the cloud is:

```
var accountSid = 'myAccountSid'; 
    var authToken = "{{ auth_token }}"; 

// Include the Twilio Cloud Module and initialize it
var twilio = require("twilio");
twilio.initialize(accountSid,authToken);

// Create the Cloud Function
Parse.Cloud.define("inviteWithTwilio", function(request, response) {
                   // Use the Twilio Cloud Module to send an SMS
                   twilio.sendSMS({
                                  From: "myTwilioPoneNumber",
                                  To: request.params.number,
                                  Body: "Start using Parse and Twilio!"
                                  }, {
                                  success: function(httpResponse) { response.success("SMS sent!"); },
                                  error: function(httpResponse) { response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong"); }
                                  });
                   });
```

The code in my app: ViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)sendMessageButton:(id)sender {
    NSString *toPhoneNumber =@"+1819873435";//etc.
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:number forKey:@"number"];
    // Call our Cloud Function that sends an SMS with Twilio
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"inviteWithTwilio"
                       withParameters:params
                                block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
                                }];
}
```

I'M a client developer and i don't have any solutions.
How can i fix the error?

Comment: i think in development mode of Twilio account you have to register the number for sending verfication code.

Comment: i did. i'm trying to send a sms to my private phone number.

Comment: your number is added to twilio developer application?

Comment: the "from" number is the twilio number that i gat, and the "to" number is my phone number that i Confirmed from twilio.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

It looks like you're trying to use an old version of the Twilio Cloud module in Parse. You no longer have to call `initialize` and the `sendSMS` function takes a callback that receives error and response arguments. The code should look more like this:

```
var accountSid = 'myAccountSid'; 
    var authToken = "{{ auth_token }}"; 

// Include the Twilio Cloud Module and initialize it
var twilio = require("twilio")(accountSid, authToken);

// Create the Cloud Function
Parse.Cloud.define("inviteWithTwilio", function(request, response) {
  // Use the Twilio Cloud Module to send an SMS
  twilio.sendSMS({
    From: "myTwilioPoneNumber",
    To: request.params.number,
    Body: "Start using Parse and Twilio!"
  }, function(err, response) {
    if (!err) {
      response.success("SMS sent!");
    } else {
      response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: i tried this code, but it's still giving me error: TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'sendSMS'
    at main.js:23:27 (Code: 141, Version: 1.12.0)

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. This is the documentation I was following: https://parse.com/docs/cloudcode/guide#cloud-code-modules-twilio and it shows how to require and initialise the module.